# How to control component use left arrow and right arrow keyboard an angular2

Tags: angular, tabindex

I want to use Left Arrow and Right Arrow to control the button which is drawed by rect.drag-area.But when I use tab keyboard to focus on the button,I don't know how to control the button.

```
        g.draggable((mousedown)='onMouseDown("start", $event.clientX)',[attr.transform]='"translate(" + startX() + ", 0)"', aria-label="timeWindowArrowLeft",tabindex="0")
            polygon.arrow(points='-13,-10 -13,10 0,0')
            rect.drag-area(width='13', height='20', x='-13', y='-10')
```

[image]
When I press the Left arrow,the left button can been pushed

Comment: listen keyboard event when control component active.

Comment: `(keydown.ArrowLeft)=""` for example

Comment: @Carsten,thanks,I have tried,and I want to use Left Arrow to control a button which is drawed by rect.drag-area,for example,when I press Left Arrow ,the button should move to left.so my idea is to get the x coordinate，so how can I get the x coordinate,when I use tab keyboard to focus on this button.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari thanks, if I want to get the x  coordinate,when I use tab keyboard focus this button,what can I do?